# Using a hyphen in a sentence

Tags: hyphens

I typed the following sentence for grammar checking:

> It seems I am quite close, but the errors are **time consuming** to resolve sometimes.

It converted it to:

> It seems I am quite close, but the errors are **time-consuming** to resolve sometimes.

Which adds a hyphen in between "time" and "consuming".

Is the one without the hyphen incorrect or conveys a different meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen improves the expression.  "time-consuming" is a compound word (rather than a subject-verb clause) and by hyphenation, you indicate that this is a compound.

It's not a major issue, the sentence is easily understandable with or without a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

In general, **most styles guides** will not use a hyphen for: time consuming.

However, if *time consuming* is **an adjective that precedes a noun**, it does take an hyphen:

**This is a time-consuming task**.

**This task is very *time consuming***.

Grammarly explains this [pretty well](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen/#:%7E:text=Hyphen%20with%20a%20noun%2C%20adjective,looking%20flowers%20in%20the%20garden.) with other examples.

Also, here is my answer to this question:

[my answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117449/usage-of-time-consuming-as-a-noun/117464#117464)

- A fun-loving child
  versus for example: This child is fun loving.
- An alcohol-fueled evening
  An evening that was alcohol fueled.
- A gun-toting bandit
  A bandit toting a gun.

**Only the adjectives that precede the noun have  hyphens.**